# multi array in select option javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

my array result from ajax:

```
[
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
            {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
                {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
                {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
            ]},
            {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3}
        ]}
    ]},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
    ]}
]
```

I need get this list in select list, now I have this code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../ajax/get_parent',
        data: ({ cat: all }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var sel = document.getElementById('parentvalue');
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = "Select";
            opt.value = "";
            sel.appendChild(opt);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i]['title']) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.innerHTML = data[i]['title'];
                    opt.value = data[i]['id'];
                    sel.appendChild(opt);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and I get only one level array, I need all subs,

How can I solve this?

I need

```
- hello
    -- hello
        --- hello
            --- hello
            --- hello
- hello
    -- hello
```

Thank

Comment: Would be very helpful if you create an snippet in order to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you can just tell us what is your expected output?

Comment: @xianshenglu I'm edit, you can see up. thank you

Comment: if you can change your expected output to an array or json,that would be perfect

Comment: you have to explore inner arrays with some kind of recursion pattern ; create a function to add items into the select, create a function to loop through a array of items and if one item is an array, call again the last function on it.

Comment: Selects cannot have other selects within them. Use `<li>` with `<ul>`s inside. `list-style-type:none;`. You can just make a recursive function to produce the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively parse your array to check all the children elements as well...

```js
var data = [
    {id: 1, title: 'hello1', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 3, title: 'hello2', parent: 1, children: [
            {id: 4, title: 'hello3', parent: 3, children: [
                {id: 5, title: 'hello4', parent: 4},
                {id: 6, title: 'hello5', parent: 4}
            ]},
            {id: 7, title: 'hello6', parent: 3}
        ]}
    ]},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello7', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 8, title: 'hello8', parent: 2}
    ]}
]

function getKeys(data){
  var arr = [];
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
     arr.push({title: data[i].title, id: data[i].id});
     
     if(data[i].hasOwnProperty("children")){
        var nestedArr = getKeys(data[i].children);
        if(nestedArr){
          arr = arr.concat(nestedArr);
        }
     }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

var _d = getKeys(data);
console.log(_d);
// Use _d to generate the select dropdown now
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is some mismatch in list's parent value.

You can achieve that with a recursive function. Try the following way:

```js
var list = [
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
        {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 2, children: [
            {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
                {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
                {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
            ]},
            {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3}
        ]}
    ]},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
        {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
    ]}
]
var html = '';
function createLI(list){
  html += '<ul>';
  list.forEach(function(item){
    html += '<li>' + item.parent + ': ' + item.title + '</li>';
    if(item.children){
      createLI(item.children);
    }
    html += '</li>';
  })
  html += '</ul>';
}

createLI(list);
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```